# запись в последнюю строку на другом листе

Tags: excel, vba

Добрый день! Нужно записать в последнюю заполненную строчку столбца "А" определенное значение.  Вот этот код записывает в текущий лист, а мне нужно в конкретный. Как исправить?

```
Dim ra As Range
Set ra = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
ra = TextBox6.Value
```

Comment: Как вариант, повесил на кнопку Sheets("нужный лист").Select, это работает, но может есть более аккуратный способ?

Comment: Чтобы в конкретный лист, измените строку. `Set ra = Worksheets("нужный лист").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)` Можно даже всё это выражение записать в одну строку: `Worksheets("нужный лист").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = TextBox6.Value`

Answer (score 1):

Сам разобрался

```
' Пишем в столбец А
    Dim ra As Range
    Set ra = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    ra = TextBox6.Value

' Пишем в столбец В
    Dim ra1 As Range
    Set ra1 = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1) ' с помощью Offset сдвигаем вниз на ноль, вправо на 1
    ra1 = TextBox7.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub SaveRow()
Dim lRws As Long
    With ActiveSheet ' заменить на нужный лист
        ' первая пустая (после заполненных) строка в столбце A
        lRws = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Cells(lRws, 1).Value = TextBox6.Value ' запись в ячейку
    End With
End Sub
```

[Практически дубль темы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/519317/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-excel-vba)