# Определение последней ячейки в excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, макросы

Добрый день, есть вот такая табличка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно находить последнюю заполненную строчку столбца "А", а потом записать в столбцы  "a,b,c,d.." следующей строки информацию.

Этот код записывает в последнюю заполненную строку "А"

```
 Dim ra As Range
    Set ra = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    ra = TextBox6.Value
```

Но если использовать этот метод, то столбец "B" запишет в строку 2, а столбец "А " в строку 5. А нужно, чтобы оба были записаны в 5ую строчку

Comment: Не стоит отмечать вопросы меткой [tag:microsoft]. Она не добавляет смысла, т.к. слишком общая.

Answer (score 1):

1 Способ - использовать смещение диапазона вправо и переназначать ra

```
Dim ra as Range
Set ra = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
ra = TextBox6.Value
Set ra = ra.Offset(0,1)
ra = TextBox7.Value
```

и повторять последние 2 строки столько раз, сколько нужно

2 Способ - просто использовать однажды вычисленный номер последней строки

```
Dim ra as Range
Set ra = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
ra = TextBox6.Value
Range("B" & ra.Row) = TextBox7.Value
Range("C" & ra.Row) = TextBox8.Value
```

и так далее

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub SaveRow()
Dim lRws As Long
    With ActiveSheet ' заменить на нужный лист
        ' первая пустая (после заполненных) строка в столбце A
        lRws = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        ' заполнение ячеек случайными числами:
        Randomize ' запуск генератора случайных чисел
        .Cells(lRws, 1).Value = Rnd()
        .Cells(lRws, 2).Value = Rnd()
        .Cells(lRws, 3).Value = Rnd()
        .Cells(lRws, 4).Value = Rnd()
    End With
End Sub
```