# Если ячейка пуста, взять значение из соседней ячейки Excel VBA

Tags: vba

Цикл проходит, а значение не берется :(
Подскажите, как можно обратиться к соседней ячейкe(из колонки J)

```
Dim i As Long, n As Long
With Columns("I")
    n = .Cells.Count
        For i = 1 To n
            If .Cells(i).Value = 0 And IsEmpty(.Cells(i)) = True Then
                .Cells(i).Value = .Cells(i, i + 1).Value
            End If
        Next
End With
```

Comment: `IsEmpty` определит, не пустая ли ячейка. *True* вернет на всем - формула, число, пустая строка, буль... Это ли нужно? Да и прямое назначение оператора - проверка инициализации переменных... Уточните, Какие данные в столбце - ищем текст? число? И лучше показывать не только код, но и пример с данными. Если последняя строка с данными далеко внизу (большой диапазон), лучше искать в массиве

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перебирать все 1048576 ячеек в столбце избыточно, лучше ограничиться .UsedRange или найти [последнюю ячейку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/519317/%d0%9e%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%8f%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-excel-vba) и перебирать до нее.
Чтобы обратиться к ячейке справа, используйте смещение `.Offset(, 1)`.

```
Sub test2()
    Dim cl
    For Each cl In Intersect(ActiveSheet.Columns("I"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        If IsEmpty(cl) Then cl.Value = cl.Offset(, 1)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Cпасибо огромное! А еще не подскажите, как задать условие, что слева ячейка(колонка H)  НЕ пустая?(Забыл про это написать) `.Offset(, -1)` в условии результата не дал, увы и второй `For` тоже :(

Comment: `If IsEmpty(cl) and Not IsEmpty(cl.offset(,-1)) Then ...`

Comment: Спасибо огромное еще раз!:))

Comment: простите за беспокойство
Только недавно заметил интересную задачу:
После примерно 500 строк, заполнение в ячейках с соседом снизу(в одном столбце "i") имеют одинаковые значения (хотя их сосед справа в столбце "J" другой)

Пробовал: 
Очищать переменную в конце блока if. 
Через другие переменные и их очищением результат тот же

В основном ячейка содержит текст и числа, которые попадаются тоже формата текст

Comment: Таблица: Вопрос(столбец H) - комментарий(столбец I) - ответ (столбец J) / после 2-4 неправильные ответы вниз и набор ячеек повторяется. С радостью бы отправил свои файлы, но увы работаю в гос. компании

Comment: @SemKop без кода и примеров данных ничего не понятно. Вы можете дополнить вопрос или создать новый. Данные можно использовать фиктивные.